# How to start a new activity from a non activity class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an application which reads heart rate from the finger using camera lens. I want after it's done with previewing the image to pass the results to a new `Activity`.
I want to open the next `Activity` which is `Results.kt`.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
if (Beats != 0) {
    var intent = Intent(this, Results::class.java)
    ContextCompat.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: What type of class is this? Are you passing any context of this class from an activity?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a proper `Context` available, you can start your `Results` as follow:

```
if (Beats != 0) {
    var intent = Intent(context, Results::class.java)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

If your non-activity class does not have access to a `Context` right now, you should inject it somewhere (during creation of your object as a passed-in argument for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `this` as it's not an `Activity` and therefore not a `Context`. You have to provide a proper `Context` and can also pass flag saying new task:

```
 if (Beats != 0) {
      var intent = Intent(MyClass.this.context, Results::class.java)
      MyClass.this.context.startActivity(intent)
  }
```

Here replace `MyClass` with your class name. Not sure if it will work or not.